# Firestore Offline Persistence does not sync in Ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore with Ionic. I have used the offline persistence, as below (I have added all of the firestore modules that I am using)

```
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule.enablePersistence(),
    AngularFireStorageModule,
    AngularFireMessagingModule,
```

However I find that I am having stale data on my mobile. Updates using another mobile to the firestore collection does not reflect on my mobile. If I remove offline persistence, then it is reflecting accurately.

So I added a refresh option as below:

```
this.firestore.collection(col, ref => ref.orderBy('modifiedAt', 'desc').limit(1)).get({ source: 'server' }).subscribe(doc => alert(doc['name']));
```

When I refresh, I get the last modified document from the server. But when I check my list, I still find stale data. Anyone has faced this problem?

Versions:

```
    "@angular/common": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.1.4",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.5.2",
    "firebase": "^8.0.0",
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with "stale data on your mobile"? Offline persistence should allow you to access a cached copy of the data when the device is offline. Then when device goes online, local changes should be synchronized to the backend.  When you do updates using another mobile, is that mobile offline? If it works ok with offline persistence removed, then what are you testing?

Comment: @JavierA, Thank you for your comment. I have an app that my team uses. Everyone is a assigned a task through the app. When someone updates status of the  work, It does not reflect om my mobile. When I refresh (as mentioned in my query), I see the last modified task (with an alert). But when I check my list of task, I do not see the updated status. Since I can see the last modified task which is coming from the server, I know I am online. I am not able to figure out how to troubleshoot this problem